# Redirect domain/directory to domain2/directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias, mask

I would like domain1.com/customers to go to domain2 my home directory public html's folder / customers. Both domains are on different servers. In the folder on the second server/second domain we will run several test sites for our clients.Sites like domain2.com/henry/index.php. Both sites are on LAMP servers. To redirect domain one to two I could use a DNS redirect.

I do want to keep the domain domain1/directory shown in the browser address bar so I think I have to use *domain masking* for this.

I found this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962605/url-masking-with-dns-and-or-mod-rewrite).  This is based on Mod rewrite tasks I believe. But to me that is just a standard 301 redirect. And that is not what I need here. I need masking as well.

I found a better redirect still [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979618/apache-htaccess-redirect-301-old-domain-to-new-domain-with-page-name-changes-as):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

But I still am not sure whether this would mask the final domain so constitutes url masking which I need. Reading on it at [WebGUI](http://www.webgui.org/community-wiki/url-masking) atm. To mask the url they have this example:

```
# mask real url
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [P,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/media
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [P,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [P,L]

        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/dir/ [P,L]
```

The P stands for Proxy and L for last. Proxy is needed for masking as far as I understood so far. Flags explained [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html).

My hoster said I should probably use Apache Alias. [Apache Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) does also take care of internal redirects so I guess he is right as far as making sure data on the second domain/server is loaded from the proper location. He mentions using:

```
<VirtualHost domain2.com:80>
   …configuratie…
   Alias /customers /var/www/html/customers
</VirtualHost>
```

Question: How do I keep domain1/directory in the browser address bar and make it load sites from domain2/directory such use domain2.com/customers/peter/idex.php /henry/index.php and so on ?

Comment: Reading on domain masking here http://www.webgui.org/community-wiki/url-masking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using a new test domain and going for a DNS redirect to the ip of the test server in question. This as this initial trial seems to hard to do and would require server one to do extra unnecessary lifting.